# syntax error in adding the element to super scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, super, traits

i have some trouble with super method. i need to define a function in map, which can increase the value in key-value pairs.

```
trait AddOneToMap[K] extends Map[K,Long] {

abstract override def get(key: K): Option[Long] = super.get(key) + 1.0}
```

but i've got the mistake: type mismatch;

```
found   : Double(1.0)
 required: String
 abstract override def get(key: K): Option[Long] = super.get(key) + 1.0
```

how to solve this problem?                                                                       ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's expand the function to:

```
def get(key: K): Option[Long] = {
  val x: Option[Long] = super.get(key)
  x + 1.0
}
```

Now it's clear that you are adding a `Double` to an `Option[Long]`. (Did you mean to add a `Long` rather than a `Double`?)
What you want to do is add 1 to the lookup *if it succeeds*.

Here's the idiomatic way to do this:

```
def get(key: K): Option[Long] = super.get(key).map(_ + 1L)
```